# Blinking selectedindex on listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to refresh a listview using a `timer`.
the code works fine, however the problem is that the `selectedindex` is blinking maybe because the data/ui reloads itself every 1sec.

what I want, when the user navigate I want the `selectedindex` to retain without blinking the currentlist highlight.

the `145` transaction number there is highlighted... it blinks the highlight every 1 sec due to timer. how can I prevent it from blinking? thanks in advance...

[image]

here's my code:

```
    public OrderCashieringView()
    {
        Timer time = new Timer();
        time.Interval = (10 * 100);
        time.Tick += time_Tick;
        time.Start();
    }


    void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstOrders.IsDisposed == false)
        {
            int CurrentRow = lstOrders.SelectedIndex;
            LoadDataCore();
            lstOrders.SelectedIndex = CurrentRow;
        }
    }


    void LoadDataCore()
    {
            if (txtSearchOrderNumber.Text == String.Empty)
            {
                _model = svc.GetForPayment();
            }
            else
            {
                _model = svc.GetForPayment().Where(a => a.TransactionNumber.Contains(txtSearchOrderNumber.Text)).ToArray();
            }

            if (lstOrders.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                {
                    lstOrders.DataSource = _model.ToArray();
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                lstOrders.DataSource = _model.ToArray();
            }

    }
```

Comment: Call the list view's `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` methods where appropriate.

Comment: @SamAxe uhmm... is it before and after the `LoadDataCore`?

Comment: Read the documentation for those functions and you shall know.

Comment: @SamAxe can you provide me some links to it? I'm really new to this so bear with me..

Comment: Sure, here you go:  http://goo.gl/LLPF68

Comment: @SamAxe LMAO, Nice job there...!!

Comment: @SamAxe the same problem occur... =(

Answer (score 0):

Try binding SelectedValue of the Listview to a property, I assume after refreshing selection will persist. SelectedIndex will refresh with the new data binded to the list.
If you specifically need SelectedIndex, you can find the index of the selected value from the list you are binding to the listview.

Comment: hmmm I don't really get it.. you mean I bind the selected index on the data that I bind?

Comment: are you using WPF? I was talking about binding  SelectedValue of list in Xaml to a property and selection will remain after refresh. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am using telerik winforms..... I don't know how to bind the values of my lists to xaml yet sir... what I am doing is I'm creating a Model Class and store the values there....